# What are these C directives doing and why was this library built this way?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, software-design

I'm navigating the [following library](https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic) and I have trouble understanding how several functions work, what they are doing, and why the library was built in that way. The library provides cryptographic tools.

For instance, in a file containing a test, an object `g1_t` is initialized in the following way:

```c
g1_t a;
g1_new(a);
g1_null(a);
```

Found in: `test_pc.c`

The functions `g1_new()`, `g1_null()`, among many others, are defined as macros such as:

```c
#define g1_null(A)          CAT(G1_LOWER, null)(A)
#define g1_new(A)           CAT(G1_LOWER, new)(A)
```

Found in: `relic_pc.h`

Where `CAT` is again a macro defined as:

```c
#define CAT(A, B)           _CAT(A, B)
```

and subsequently,

```c
#define _CAT(A, B)          A ## B
```

Found in: `relic_util.h`

Furthermore, `G1_LOWER` is defined as:

```c
#define G1_LOWER            ep_
```

Found in:`relic_pc.h`

I understand basic preprocessing directives. For instance, I understand that `##` is concatenating two tokens. However, I can't see how these directives are able to create/nullify (among many other things) the object `g1_t`. This design format is quite foreign to me. Could anybody provide some insight as to what these directives do and why was the software built in such a way (i.e. advantages)?

Comment: `g1_new(a)` expands to `ep_new(a)`, where `ep_new` is presumably a function or another macro.

Comment: So `ep_new(a)` and `ep_null(a)`is called. But you can configure your compiler to output the preprocessor output to a file, Then you can look at it.

Comment: Look at the output from the preprocessor. That's the code that will actually be executed, you can work backwards from there.

Comment: github hosts the library. Studying the output of `git log` might be helpful. Might not. (I'm assuming you already read whatever comments are in the code.)

Comment: Ridiculous programming style. Source of the almost undebuggable problems. Bloody "masters of the preprocessing", gluing function names at compilation time. Hard to find anything more stupid.

Comment: The answer as usual will be "historical reasons". Generally the source code was once (and perhaps is still) compiled for multiple platforms using multiple compilers with different dialects of C and/or restrictions and/or compatibility requirements. ISO C11 didn't always exist and much current code dates from the pre-C11 era (or indeed the pre-C89 era).

Comment: Maybe the lib was converted from another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as usual will be "historical reasons". Generally the source code was once (and perhaps is still) compiled for multiple platforms using multiple compilers with different dialects of C and/or restrictions and/or compatibility requirements.

For example:

- compatibility with another library which defined those functions with different names
- compatibility with a compiler/linker platform which had severe restrictions on the length of identifiers
- Fossil code from a migration/refactoring exercise in which all the functions were renamed
- a product differentiation exercise in which subsets of functionality are compiled from the same codebase with different function names (or leftovers from such an exercise)

The C language is 45 years old: ISO C11 didn't always exist and much code which is in use, maintained, and regularly compiled, dates from the pre-C11 era (or indeed the pre-C89 era).

**In this case** I note that there is a comment in the GitHub history which says "integrate ED module with EC module". Probably this has something to do with that type of exercise, e.g. allowing certain common functions to be called in different compilation units under different names.